# After a power failure my XP looks like Windows 2000

Tags: windows, desktop, windows-explorer, taskbar

After a sudden power failure my WinXP machine shows the taskbar in Win2k style and I can't find any reasonable change in settings that could get the XP look back. What should I look for?

Comment: You say that like it's a bad thing.

Comment: maybe you have no idea what win2k can look like with a little help :) you mean 'windows classic style".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the display control panel and select the XP style of choice. If those options are not available, make sure that the theme service is running. Go into control panel, then choose administrative tools. Look for a service that has the word theme in it. Right click that service and choose properties. Make sure its startup type is automatic. Click ok. Right click the service and choose start. Your themes should either immediately return, or you may still need the display control panel steps above.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the desktop, choose 'Properties' from the context menu, go to the 'Appearance' tab. You can now select the XP style buttons, color schemes etc that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try John's Solution. If that fails then may be your Windows has got corrupted. Just [repair](http://www.webtree.ca/windowsxp/repair_xp.htm) it using your Windows CD.